# How to get directory from URL?

Tags: javascript

I have a subdomain that's dedicated to redirecting traffic that hits it.

The URL should always be similar to this:  `http://test.example.com/12345/`

I'm trying to figure out how to get `12345` and assign that to a javascript variable.

If that directory isn't set or it isn't numeric (so there's nothing to set the variable to), I'd prefer to just set the variable to `11111`.

I've read a few answers on StackOverflow saying that similar can't be done with pure javascript, which seems odd to me.  But then again, I'm certainly no expert...

UPDATE: I understand that `pathname` can be used to get the path itself, but I'm not sure how to remove the trailing `/` and verify that it's numeric.

Comment: basic reg exp can do it

Comment: `location.pathname`, try that.